# An encryption algorithm which accepts a string and does the following steps to mask the string

Tags: python

Following steps:

1. Sorts the input in descending order
   For example:
   **Input** = "`zebra`"
   **Output** = "`aberz`
2. Replace the following letters into numeric
   `a` => `0`
   `j` => `9`
   `o` => `14`
   `z` => `25`
   **Sample Output** = "`0ber25`"
3. Adds the word "sym" at the start of the word
   **Final Output** = "`sym0ber25`"

I already have a code but it doesn't pass the asserts. Can someone help me on how to improve my code? Also, do I need to add a return statement?

```
def exercise_8(word):
    strword = list(word)
    sortedWord=''.join(sorted(strword, reverse= True))
    dict = {"a": "0", "j":"1","o":"14","z":"25"}
    num = sortedWord[::-1]
    for i in dict:
        num = num.replace(i, dict[i])
        print(f"sym{num}")
```

This is the output I get

```
`sym0berz
sym0berz
sym0berz
sym0ber25
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-f9c4c7f1d71c> in <module>
      1 ans = exercise_8("zebra")
----> 2 assert ans=="sym0ber25"
      3 
      4 ans = exercise_8("banana")
      5 assert ans=="sym000bnn"

AssertionError: `
```

Comment: The ordering shown is in ascending, not descending order

Comment: This is not an encryption. Not even a bad one! It does not fulfill the definition of an encryption, which would require the process to be reversible. But the sorting step is irreversible. There's multiple plaintext words that lead to the same sorted letter sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you can see, the assert statement checks the value that your function returns. So, you will have to return the value. Nobody seems to have asked you to print it!